# Kotlin about passing lambda as property

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

I am confusing about merit of writing code as following 2 case:

```
class TestA {
    private val foo: Boolean by lazy {
        // Here is logic that return true or false
    }  
    Case 1:
    fun main() {  
        TestB({foo})
    }
    Case 2:
    fun main() {
        TestB(foo)
    }

}
Case 1:
class TestB(private val isFoo: () -> Boolean ) {
    fun checkFoo(): Boolean {
        return isFoo.invoke()
    }
}

Case 2:
class TestB(private val isFoo: Boolean ) {
    fun checkFoo(): Boolean {
        return isFoo
    }
}
```

When should I use case 1 or case 2 ?
By the way, please let me know how does invoke() method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.invoke()` will simply call your lambda and give your result, same as calling a function.

As for when you should pass a lambda or an actual value, it very depends.

Personally, I would only suggest using lambdas in very specific situations, overusing them can make your code very confusing and hard to refactor. If you just want a result to be passed into the function, just pass the actual value. Don't make someone else call `.invoke()`.

But a few good example for a lambda are callsbacks, or onClickListeners.

```
// A login network request with a lambda handling the result.
fun login( username: String, password: String, onResult: (Result) -> Unit ) {
    // do some network call, and return a Result.
}

// note: if the last param is a lambda, you can simply move it outside the function call like this.
login( username, password ) { result ->
    // use the result of the network request.
}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @Active-Dog ! I accepted your answer . One more thing that I want to confirm about my understanding is : If I pass lambda as case 1, can performance be better ? Because I think that lambda actual run when checkFoo() is called ? is that correct ?

Comment: @miho39 I don't think you'll notice any performance difference, but I'm not 100% sure. You are passing a larger data structure though, so that may effect things.

Answer (score 2):

You only pass lambdas into other class constructors if you want something to be invoked on the other end, that might make sense if used as a callback, or if you need to have a function that creates objects again and again rather than being static. In this case, you'd store the lambda for later referral and invoke it whenever needed. If you just pass a static instance around, that is for example `foo` in your code, there's no reason for a lambda. You should always prefer not to use lambdas for constructors; scenarios in which they are useful or necessary are rather rare IMO.

As to your question regarding `invoke`: Kotlin has a number of functions that work "by convention", e.g. `rangeTo`, `equals`, `contains`, `compareTo`, the index operators and also `invoke`. Learn about conventions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html).

Now, whenever a class provides the `invoke` operator, you can call instances of that class as if they were functions:

```
class InvokeMe(){
    operator fun invoke(value: Int) = println("invoked with $value")
}

val obj = InvokeMe()
//both are compiled to the same code
obj(10)
obj.invoke(5)
```

Since every lambda is being compiled into a `Function` instance (see `kotlin.jvm.functions`) which comes with an implementation of `invoke`, you can call lambdas as shown above, i.e., using `lambda(args)` or `lambda.invoke(args)`